# Canvas not rotating after calling setTransform

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have an HTML5 canvas in which I'm drawing a line and rotating it around the center. I would like to reset the canvas's transformation each time I draw and then re-translate/rotate the canvas, but it doesn't seem to rotate. I have a working example in which I store the previous rotation and only rotate by the difference in angle (obviously, in this example I don't reset the transformation) but in the unsanitized version of this code it doesn't provide an adequate workaround.

I've created two fiddles, [the first version](https://jsfiddle.net/davemcclelland/d6ww5gqw/) in which I reset the transform and it doesn't function properly and [the second version](https://jsfiddle.net/davemcclelland/0rsx3rep/) in which I store the difference in angles and it functions properly. Snippets copied below. **How can I adapt the second version to function the same way that as the first?**

## First version (functional, undesired implementation)

```js
(function () {    
    // dynamic canvas
    var dynamic = document.getElementById("dynamic");
    var dynamicCtx = dynamic.getContext("2d");
    
    // animation status
    var FPS = 10;
    var INTERVAL = 1000 / FPS;
    
    dynamicCtx.translate(dynamic.width/2, dynamic.width/2);
    var previousRotation_rad = 0;
    var rotationCounter_deg = 0;

    var myDynamicObject = {
      center: dynamic.width / 2,
        length: dynamic.width * 0.4,
        draw: function () {   // example of dynamic animation code
          dynamicCtx.clearRect(-this.center, -this.center, 2*this.center, 2*this.center);
            
            // draw the current rotation angle
            dynamicCtx.textBaseline = 'middle';
            dynamicCtx.textAlign = 'center';
            dynamicCtx.fillText(rotationCounter_deg + '°', 0, -this.length);
            
            // draw a line from the center up
            dynamicCtx.beginPath();
            dynamicCtx.moveTo(0, 0);
            dynamicCtx.lineTo(0, -this.length + 20);
            dynamicCtx.stroke();
            
            // rotate the canvas
            var currentRotation_rad = rotationCounter_deg * Math.PI / 180;
            var rotationDifference_rad = currentRotation_rad - previousRotation_rad;
            previousRotation_rad = currentRotation_rad;
            console.log('rotating', rotationDifference_rad, 'radians');
            dynamicCtx.rotate(rotationDifference_rad);
           ++rotationCounter_deg;
        }
    };

    function drawDynamic() {        
        myDynamicObject.draw();
        // you can add more dynamic objects and draw here
    }

    function animate() {
        setInterval(function () {
            // only need to redraw dynamic objects
            drawDynamic();
        }, INTERVAL);
    }

    animate(); // entry point for animated (dynamic) objects
})();
```

```css
#canvasesdiv {
    position:relative;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
}
#dynamic {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="canvasesdiv">
    <canvas id="dynamic" width=400 height=400>This text is displayed if your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas</canvas>
</div>
```

## Second version (non-functional, desired implementation)

```js
(function () {    
    // dynamic canvas
    var dynamic = document.getElementById("dynamic");
    var dynamicCtx = dynamic.getContext("2d");
    
    // animation status
    var FPS = 10;
    var INTERVAL = 1000 / FPS;
    
    var rotationCounter_deg = 0;

    var myDynamicObject = {
      center: dynamic.width / 2,
        length: dynamic.width * 0.4,
        draw: function () {   // example of dynamic animation code
          dynamicCtx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
        dynamicCtx.translate(dynamic.width/2, dynamic.width/2);
          dynamicCtx.clearRect(-this.center, -this.center, 2*this.center, 2*this.center);
            
            // draw the current rotation angle
            dynamicCtx.textBaseline = 'middle';
            dynamicCtx.textAlign = 'center';
            dynamicCtx.fillText(rotationCounter_deg + '°', 0, -this.length);
            
            // draw a line from the center up
            dynamicCtx.beginPath();
            dynamicCtx.moveTo(0, 0);
            dynamicCtx.lineTo(0, -this.length + 20);
            dynamicCtx.stroke();
            
            // rotate the canvas
            var currentRotation_rad = rotationCounter_deg * Math.PI / 180;
            console.log('rotating', currentRotation_rad, 'radians');
            dynamicCtx.rotate(currentRotation_rad);
           ++rotationCounter_deg;
        }
    };

    function drawDynamic() {        
        myDynamicObject.draw();
        // you can add more dynamic objects and draw here
    }

    function animate() {
        setInterval(function () {
            // only need to redraw dynamic objects
            drawDynamic();
        }, INTERVAL);
    }

    animate(); // entry point for animated (dynamic) objects
})();
```

```css
#canvasesdiv {
    position:relative;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
}
#dynamic {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="canvasesdiv">
    <canvas id="dynamic" width=400 height=400>This text is displayed if your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas</canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike for example CSS, the canvas context renders intermediate so all transforms must be applied *before* anything is drawn.

Simply move the rotation transform up before you draw to the canvas as well as the declaration:

```js
(function() {
  // dynamic canvas
  var dynamic = document.getElementById("dynamic");
  var dynamicCtx = dynamic.getContext("2d");

  // animation status
  var FPS = 10;
  var INTERVAL = 1000 / FPS;

  var rotationCounter_deg = 0;

  var myDynamicObject = {
    center: dynamic.width / 2,
    length: dynamic.width * 0.4,
    draw: function() { // example of dynamic animation code
      var currentRotation_rad = rotationCounter_deg * Math.PI / 180;

      dynamicCtx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
      dynamicCtx.translate(dynamic.width / 2, dynamic.width / 2);
      dynamicCtx.clearRect(-this.center, -this.center, 2 * this.center, 2 * this.center);
      dynamicCtx.rotate(currentRotation_rad);

      // draw the current rotation angle
      dynamicCtx.textBaseline = 'middle';
      dynamicCtx.textAlign = 'center';
      dynamicCtx.fillText(rotationCounter_deg + '°', 0, -this.length);

      // draw a line from the center up
      dynamicCtx.beginPath();
      dynamicCtx.moveTo(0, 0);
      dynamicCtx.lineTo(0, -this.length + 20);
      dynamicCtx.stroke();

      // rotate the canvas
      console.log('rotating', currentRotation_rad, 'radians');
      ++rotationCounter_deg;
    }
  };

  function drawDynamic() {
    myDynamicObject.draw();
    // you can add more dynamic objects and draw here
  }

  function animate() {
    setInterval(function() {
      // only need to redraw dynamic objects
      drawDynamic();
    }, INTERVAL);
  }

  animate(); // entry point for animated (dynamic) objects
})();
```

```css
#canvasesdiv {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
#dynamic {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="canvasesdiv">
  <canvas id="dynamic" width=400 height=400>This text is displayed if your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas</canvas>
</div>
```

Bonus tip: you can also merge `setTransform()` and the first `translate()`:

```
dynamicCtx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
dynamicCtx.translate(dynamic.width / 2, dynamic.width / 2);
```

to:

```
dynamicCtx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, dynamic.width * 0.5, dynamic.width * 0.5);
```

Comment: I think I was being thrown of my some past experiences. This seems obvious now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are rotating the canvas after drawing the content. Rotate first and it works fine.

Comment: Can you expand on your answer with some example code?